# Integrate Grunt with Visual Studio publish option

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, publishing, webdeploy, task-runner-explorer

I want to execute grunt task when I publish my web application for either dev/test/production.

Right now, when I build my solution, at that time I've configured to execute grunt task.But,when I publish my web app it doesn't execute even if visual studio builds solution before publishing.

Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified the Visual Studio version. I found this works with the VS 2015 and .Net core

I have used Grunt & Project.JSON files for accomplishing this.

**Grunt.JS**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');


    grunt.initConfig({

        uglify: {
            options: {
                mangle: false,
                beautify: true
            },
            my_target: {
                files: {
                    'wwwroot/app/app.js':
                        [
                             'wwwroot/*.js',
                             'wwwroot/services/*.js',
                             'wwwroot/view/**/*.js',
                             'wwwroot/common/*.js'
                        ]
                }
            }
        },        

        cssmin: {
            options: {
                shorthandCompacting: false,
                roundingPrecision: -1
            },
            target: {
                files: {
                    'wwwroot/app/app.css':
                    [
                        'wwwroot/*.css',
                        'wwwroot/view/**/*.css'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            scripts: {
                files: [
                            'wwwroot/services/*.js',
                            'wwwroot/view/**/*.js',
                            'wwwroot/*.js'
                        ],
                tasks: ['uglify']
            },
            css: {
                files: [
                        'wwwroot/*.css',
                        'wwwroot/view/**/*.css'
                        ],
                tasks: ['cssmin']
            }
        },
        clean: {
            prod: {
               src: ['wwwroot/pdf/*']
            }
        }

    });


    grunt.registerTask('build', ['uglify', 'cssmin', 'clean']);
};
```

### **Project.Json**

```
"scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "grunt build" ]

  }
```